# Catalog Nested XML with AWS Glue

Tags: xml, aws-glue

I've got XML source that I'm trying to catalog with Glue:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
          <authors>
            <author>
              <name>Gambardella, Matthew</name>
            </author>
          </authors>
       </book>
       ...
```

The book entries are being picked up just fine, but how do I configure my crawler / classifier(s) to recognize the nesting under `<authors>`?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to specify a classifier unless you want it to only capture that row tag.  Then you would want to just set the classifier to author.  However, you will not get the rest of the data.

If you use a crawler to infer the schema of the data.  It will capture what is in authors as a struct type.  See the picture below:

[image: Table schema following crawler with no classifier]

Now you can map the field within the glue job:

[image: Mappings]

Or just access the field itself within the job's code like this:

[image: Accessing the field itself]

Answer (score 1):

We had a lot of trouble loading nested XML data into the `DynamicFrame`. The problem is that you cannot use a standard Spark (PySpark in our case) `XPATH` Hive DDL statements to load the `DataFrame` (`DynamicFrame` in case of AWS GLUE).
Our solution was to load the `DynamicFrame` just using the naive and only `RowTag` parameter in the **Table Properties** (not in the **Serde Parameters** as the Crawler suggested). This will give you a single `dynamicRecord['MySingleParsedField']` that you can then iterate inside one of the Spark (GLUE) jobs to populate new fields. Here there is a working example of such iteration code:

```
def Map_Inital_Fields(dynamicRecord):
    nested = []
    for item in dynamicRecord['MySingleParsedField']:
      nested.append(item)
    dynamicRecord['title'] = [item.get('title') for item in nested[0].get('book')][0]
    dynamicRecord['price'] = [item.get('price') for item in nested[0].get('book')][0]
    del dynamicRecord['MySingleParsedField']

    return dynamicRecord
mapfields01 = Map.apply(frame = selectfields2, f = Map_Inital_Fields, transformation_ctx = "mapfields01")
```

This is just an example, but basically, once you have the xml parsed object as a field in the `DynamicFrame` you can think on it as a Python object (a dic) and then modify it as you need.